# Using main menu as toolbar in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'd like to create a toolbar that contains main menu, just like the standard main menu
at the top of the window.

Is there some fast way to do this in QT ? I know that I can create a toolbar with buttons and context menus :-)

Thx for help.

Comment: Even if it were possible, putting the main menu in a toolbar would be a bad GUI design. If the user accidentally hides that toolbar, then he/she would no longer have a way to control the program. It would also go against user expectations, because everybody is used to having the menu bar directly below the title bar.

Comment: ... unless you were to make it impossible to hide that tool bar. Oh, I see what you're trying to do. You're trying to mimic the newfangled menu system Microsoft has in Windows/Internet Explorer, aren't you?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal for having a menu in a toolbar. To be able to move the menu around or undock it?

Comment: I wan't to have my menu and toolbar in one line :) That way I can save some vertical space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any widget to QToolBar using:

```
QMenuBar *mb = new QMenuBar();
QToolBar::addWidget(mb);
```

It might be easier to reparent designer's ui->menubar to toolbar.